# MACCS Fingerprint can't be made even though I could do it with Morgan

Tags: rdkit, fingerprinting, cheminformatics

I am trying to make a MACCS Fingerprint followed by a heatmap using Python. I feel like I have an OK code since I was able to make a Morgan Fingerprint heatmap using similar code.

```
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import os
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import DataStructs
import numpy as np 
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem import MACCSkeys
from rdkit.Chem.AtomPairs import Pairs
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import MolsToGridImage
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit import DataStructs
from rdkit.DataManip.Metric import GetTanimotoDistMat
from rdkit.DataManip.Metric import GetTanimotoSimMat
from rdkit import rdBasefrom rdkit.Chem import RDConfig
```

```
sdfdir = os.path.join(RDConfig.RDDocsDir, '/Users/emmaf/Desktop/toxicitydatamaccs_toxic.sdf')

mols = [m for m in Chem.SDMolSupplier(sdfdir)]
Draw.MolsToGridImage(mols[:5], molsPerRow=5)
```

```
maccs_fp_list = [MACCSkeys.GenMACCSKeys(x) for x in mols]`
```

At this point I get stuck. What can I improve on?  I expect to get distance matrix that I would then be able to make into a heatmap.

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? The [rdkit tag at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) has 95.5% of its questions answered. If you want this question migrated there, please ping me by typing @Nike in a comment and letting me know. I'll make a case to the moderators for a migration.

Comment: Hey I would love if more people could see this @Nike please migrate it to the right spot.